# Problems in inserting images in LyX

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

Recently I have installed LyX in my Ubuntu 12.04LTS for the purpose of text editing. But I am facing some problems while inserting images. Whenever I go to the "insert graphics" option, browse the picture I want to insert and click the file (.png, .jpg), the application closes automatically. I tried to reconfigure it also but still it shows the same problem. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to TeX.SX. If you try to run application from command line, then maybe you can see what causes the crash and what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Qt's accessibility features (e.g. screen reader), you can do:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi
```

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lyx/+bug/946956 and please log in to launchpad and click on "this bug affects me".